# List of earned bounties shows the state of question, not the answer.

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, user-profile

In the profile page, when you check the list of [earned bounties](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=bounties&sort=earned), as usual it shows the titles of the questions (like in 'answers' tab). Nevertheless, it shows the score of the *questions*, not the answers.

Also when you click the link, you are directed to the question, not to the answer which you earned the bounty for.

For example, consider:

[image]

The number in the white box on left (8) is the score **of the question**. And the link brings you **to the question**. Shouldn't they be **of/to the answer**?

I am not sure whether this is a status-bydesign or a bug. So attached [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

---

Note: A similar issue with 'answers tab' has been recently [reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372716/1123444), which now appears to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

---

**P.S.:** While writing this post, I also noticed **'View all 1 bounties'**. (?)

Comment: A separate report regarding the pluralization issue is now at Meta SE: [Pluralization issue: "View all 1 bounties"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376850).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue. A fix was deployed!
Now the Earned Bounty list shows answer information instead of question information.